# Create new custom rule for all languages in SonarQube 6

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, rules, sonarqube-web

I need to add a new custom rule which will check if email is written anywhere in code. It should work for all languages but specially for PHP. I'm confused if I've to create a plugin for it or has to create a custom rule template. Any lead can be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The list of languages that support custom rules is [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Coding+Rules). In general, you're not going to be able to enforce this for "all languages" but you should be able to accomplish this for PHP by creating a plugin and implementing your rule in Java.

Comment: Is there any other short way to accomplish it? I mean by creating rule or quality profile or anything from SonarQube dashboard? I have no idea about java language. I only require to check if there is email written then display it as error.

Comment: Also I'm following this method to create plugin: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Build+Plugin...... but it always gives error when I try to build it.